# Failed to start riak - Failed to create thread

Tags: linux, erlang, riak

I'm having problems with starting up Riak on my brand new VPS. Here's what I'm getting:

```
root@xxx:/var/log/riak# riak console
Attempting to restart script through sudo -H -u riak
Exec: /usr/lib/riak/erts-5.9.1/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/1.3.2/riak             -embedded -config /etc/riak/app.config             -pa /usr/lib/riak/lib/basho-patches             -args_file /etc/riak/vm.args -- console
Root: /usr/lib/riak
Failed to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
```

It's either that or error thrown by Erlang

```
 ===== LOGGING STARTED Wed Jul 10 15:16:35 CEST 2013
                                                    =====
                                                         Exec: /usr/lib/riak/erts-   5.9.1/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/riak/releases/1.3.2/riak             -embedded -config /etc/riak/app.config             -pa /usr/lib/riak/lib/basho-patches             -args_file /etc/riak/vm.args -- console
Root: /usr/lib/riak

Crash dump was written to: /var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump
Failed to create aux thread
```

Other times it starts up but crashes shortly after... 
/usr/lib/riak/lib/os_mon-2.2.9/priv/bin/memsup: Erlang has closed.      Erlang has closed

Tried increasing stack size to 64M but still doesn't work. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What is the specification of your VPS? How much RAM do you have? Which OS? How did you install Riak? Are you using the default configuration?

Comment: It's running on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. I got 2 gigs of RAm to work with. I installed RIAK by downloading the right package for my system with Riak's website guidance. I didn't change much, I tried lowering async threads to 16. Didn't help much.
However, even though my kernel is 2.6.x I realised I don't have NPTL support. Would that cause problems with threading? Can I even modify my system on my own to get that?

Comment: I would guess something is wrong with the machines libraries. I've never seen those errors, ever.

Comment: For anyone that arrives here in the future, this question was answered on the [Riak Users mailing list](http://riak-users.197444.n3.nabble.com/Can-t-start-Riak-Erlang-crashes-immediately-Memory-problem-td4028271.html)